# Firestore Timestamp orderBy Desc

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Want to display data from Firestore in descending order.

Current code looks like this

```
useEffect(() =>{
    const newPost = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'posts',), orderBy("timestamp","desc"),(snapshot) =>{
    setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
    });
    return newPost
}, []);
```

I have declared "timestamp" to the serverTimestamp() which is correctly adding to db.

```
addDoc(collection(db, 'posts',), {
        name: "Connor",
        description: "Front End Developer",
        message: input,
        photoUrl:'',
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    }).then(postRef => console.log("Document written with ID", postRef.id));
```

How can I pull data from Firestore so it displays in descending order?

[image]

Comment: Is the data not in `desc` order? The code looks fine. Do you have any error message? A screnshot of your database and app ui would be great to see.

Comment: @TarikHuber I'm building a LinkedIn clone where users can post onto the feed. Data from an input get sent to Firestore then shown on the feed, the problem is that the posts are not in desc order but alphabetical due to the unique id given by Firestore. I'm trying to give each post a timestamp and then show in desc order.

Comment: Can you pls share the screenshots I mentioned before.

Comment: @TarikHuber Hopefully this helps, my database is firebase/firestore but I don't want to post photos of that

Comment: We would need some scrrenshots on how the data looks in your app and in the database to compare it. You just put there the scrrenshots of the code you already had in the question.

Answer (score 0):

this should work (result as at 08/08/2022)

```
 import { collection, query, getDocs, doc, orderBy} from "firebase/firestore";

useEffect(() => {
      const getData =async()=>{
          const newPost = collection(db, 'posts');
          const snapshot = await getDocs(query(newPost, orderBy("timestamp", "desc")))
          const postList =snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            setInput(postlist);
      };
      getData();
}, []);
```